# Show that $k(G)\geq2$ implies that $G$ contains at least one cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if the minimum number of vertices cut from a graph to disconnect it is greater than or equal to 2, the graph must contain at least one cycle.
How would I show this, I know that the graph must be at least 3 vertices?

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive: if the graph has no cycles, then you can disconnect it with 1 cut.

Comment: What method would you recommend doing this, Induction?

Comment: Just the definition of cycle, and of cut.

Comment: Induction sounds like overkill, a direct proof is not hard. That is: suppose you have a graph with no cycles, then find a single vertex which you can cut to disconnect the graph.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I suppose I get hung up on the difference between "Show" and "Prove". I also do not yet know what constitutes a proof and how simple/self-explanatory they can really be.

Comment: To be clear here, although you say in the text of your question "greater than $2$," what you actually mean is "at least $2,$" right?

Comment: Yes I meant greater or equal to 2.